# Get Alpha Value from float64

Tags: go, colors, byte

Im trying to convert a value from float64 **0 to 1** to an Alpha value to be used inside `color.RGBA`

e.g. `color.RGBA{255, 255, 255, 255}`

Now I need to modify the value of Alpha based on the 0 to 1

example:

```golang
...
alpha := p.Tween.Value()//returns e.g. 0.3 float64

myColor := HexToColor("#E53935")
myColor.A = 255 - uint8(alpha)

...
Update(dt) call

myColor.A = 255 - uint8(alpha)
```

This is my function for converting HEX string to RGBA. But Im creating animation in Game, where I need to gradually fade the color Alpha value.

As you can see below, my alpha value is fixed.

```golang
//HexToColor("#E53935")
func HexToColor(hex string) (c color.RGBA) {
    c.A = 0xff

    errInvalidFormat := color.RGBA{255, 255, 255, 255}

    if hex[0] != '#' {
        return errInvalidFormat
    }

    hexToByte := func(b byte) byte {
        switch {
        case b >= '0' && b <= '9':
            return b - '0'
        case b >= 'a' && b <= 'f':
            return b - 'a' + 10
        case b >= 'A' && b <= 'F':
            return b - 'A' + 10
        }

        return 0
    }

    switch len(hex) {
    case 7:
        c.R = hexToByte(hex[1])<<4 + hexToByte(hex[2])
        c.G = hexToByte(hex[3])<<4 + hexToByte(hex[4])
        c.B = hexToByte(hex[5])<<4 + hexToByte(hex[6])
    case 4:
        c.R = hexToByte(hex[1]) * 17
        c.G = hexToByte(hex[2]) * 17
        c.B = hexToByte(hex[3]) * 17
    default:
        return errInvalidFormat
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a floating point number to integer is keeping its ingeger part. Which means

```
uint8(0.1) => 0
uint8(0.9) => 0
uint8(1.0) => 1
```

You should scale the `0..1` range to the range of `uint` before converting. So you may convert it like this:

```
func alpha(f float64) uint8 {
    if f >= 1 {
        return 255
    }
    return uint8(f * 256)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about Scale. Also Is it good idea to Change the Alpha value of color.RGBA like this `color.A = 230` or is there any better function which would return `HexToColor("#E53935").WithAlpha(0.1)`

Comment: @STEEL I would just pass the alpha value to `HexToColor()`, and use that to fill `c.A`.